# Javascript, CSS at HTML Versioning using Application_BeginRequest + Redirect

Tags: c#, caching, browser-cache, durandal

Will this code do the job in javascript versioning??

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var uri = request.Url;
        var url = request.Url.ToString();

        if (url.EndsWith(".js") || url.EndsWith(".css") || url.EndsWith(".html") || url.EndsWith(".ts"))
        {
            var v = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            var newUrl = uri.LocalPath + "?version=" + v;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("changing {0} to {1}", url, newUrl));

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
        }
    }
```

upon trying to access http://localhost:1111111/App/common/Action.js the browser is redirected to http://localhost:1111111/App/common/Action.js?version=1.0.0.24754. will the javascripts in clientbrowser are invalidated when the server's version changed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed they will, changing any part of the URL will cause the browser to go off and get the resources, that includes any part of a query string. You can probably check some of this yourself, for example looking at the Network tab in Chrome developer tools:

[image]

Here the `304` status code means that the item hasn't been modified on the server, so it's possible for the browser to grab from the cache. Additionally the request above you can see the browser has actually loaded from the cache.

There is quite a nice article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203288/Automatic-JS-CSS-versioning-to-update-browser-cach) which shows how to modify the query string to include the last modified date on the file - meaning automatic free versioning.

Comment: That's great if it is, I used Application_BeginRequest + Redirect that is why i am concern that it won't work. the links on client's browser are still in http://localhost:1111111/App/common/Action.js format. then when the client side requested the .js file, the Application_BeginRequest will redirect it to the link with "?version=1.0.0.*".

Comment: @VJPPaz: Ah sorry I misunderstood. I thought you were re-writing the JavaScript includes. This may not then work, because if the browser thinks it get can get it from the cache, it'll never hit the server to do the re-direct. I'd look at modifying your JS includes instead - that's the typical way to solve this problem.